# move rotated image in any where in screen on fingur gesture

Tags: android, imageview

i want image view that rotated on double finger touch and move any where in screen and also pinch to zoom. i m developing project on image editing. in that i have two image view in frame layout in top image view i specified some frames and back side on image view i specified image which is got from use either from camera or gallery. please help.
i tried this but not work fine.

```
    imageViewFrames.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) imageViewFrames.getLayoutParams();

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                         break;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                         int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                         int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                         if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                                x_cord = windowwidth;
                         }
                         if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                                y_cord = windowheight;
                         }

                         layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                         layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;

                         imageViewFrames.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                         break;
                  default:
                         break;
                }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is work for me :

```
class EraseView extends View{

// java made easy,java

private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
private Paint   mPaint;

private Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas pcanvas;

int x = 0;
int y =0;
int r =0;

public EraseView(Context context,Bitmap bm) {
    super(context);
    Log.v("Panel", ">>>>>>");

    setFocusable(true);


    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT)); 
    mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, Blur.NORMAL));


    bitmap =  bm.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

    pcanvas = new Canvas();
    pcanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);    // drawXY will result on that Bitmap
    pcanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);


}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  



    // draw a circle that is  erasing bitmap            
    pcanvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,null);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}       

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {        
     // set parameter to draw circle on touch event
     x = (int) event.getX();
     y = (int) event.getY();

     r =20;
     // At last invalidate canvas
     invalidate();
     return true;
}
}
```